# Contact Form 7 "Send" button missing

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

There is a conflict with WooCommerce and the CSS of the Contact Form 7 in my wordpress theme (Grotte). The Send button in the Contact Form 7 is not getting displayed and I somehow have not been able to get a resolution for this. It shows if I deactivate WooCommerce though. Any suggestions?

You can see that the SEND button is not getting displayed here:
https://chinaproductsfactory.com/contact-us/

Comment: It does indeed appear that CSS is hiding the button. However I'd suggest that this is so that JavaScript  can be used to hide the button until a certain criteria is met, and once this is done the JS will change the css to reveal the send button. Firebug (which any self respecting dev should be using) is also telling me that you have some JS issues. These might be related to the problem. I'd recommend disabling all other plugins, clear your browser cache and then see if the form works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to figure out using developer tools in any modern browser. You have the following code in one of the CSS-files:

```
#respond input#submit, .wpcf7-submit {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Removing this, or at least removing the `.wpcf7-submit` part, will make it display.